# Fórmula de Bhaskara em C# com o VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Fala Pessoal! Estou a usar o Visual Studio para aprender C# ,criei um botão que ao ser clicado deve mostrar o resultado de uma fórmula de Bhaskara. Porém tudo que aparece na tela ao testar se resume em "NaN"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bhaskara
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Fórmula de Bhaskara -- */
        int a = 2, b = 2, c = 4;
        double delta, xl, xll , raizq;

        delta = (b * b) * (-4) * a * c;

        xl = ((-b) + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * a;
        xll = ((-b) - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * a;

        MessageBox.Show("O resultado do x linha é :" + xl);
        MessageBox.Show("Já o resultado de x duas linha é:" + xll);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Você fez uma verificação para o caso : `delta < 0 `?

Answer (score 8):

Reformulei o seu código com algumas correções:

**1.** Verificação para o caso de `delta < 0`;

**2 .** Correção de fórmula do `delta`;

Segue o código com as alterações (reutilizei o que já tinha escrito):

```
/*Fórmula de Bhaskara -- */
        int a = 2, b = 2, c = 4;
        double delta, xl, xll, raizq;

        delta = ((b * b) - (4 * a * c));

        if (delta >= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O resultado de X1 é :"+((-b) + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * a);
            MessageBox.Show("O resultado de X2 é: " +((-b) - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / 2 * a);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Delta < 0");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código dará certo:

```
double n1, n2, n3, resp1, resp2 ;
            n1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtA.Text);
            n2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtB.Text);
            n3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtC.Text);
            resp1 = (-n2 + Math.Sqrt(n2*n2 - 4 * n1 * n3))/ (2 * n1);

            resp2 = (-n2 - Math.Sqrt(n2*n2 - 4 * n1 * n3)) / (2 * n1);

            lblResposta.Text = "X1 = " + resp1.ToString("#0.00") + " X2 = " + resp2.ToString("#0.00");
        }
    }
```